# How to make two charged objects in Blender interact?

Tags: animation, particles, physics, force-fields

I cannot seem to do it, no matter what settings I change. I'm trying to simulate a negatively charged particle and a positively charged particle being attracted to each other. Or to simulate coulomb's law.

I parented a very low mass rigid body sphere to a "Charge" force field with a strength of +1 and flow of 1. I repeated that with another sphere with a strength of -1 and placed them apart. I disabled gravity. They should both collide but it doesn't, and I cannot figure out why.

I suspect it has something to do with the force field only working for instanced particles, but that's not helpful when I need to determine exactly where I want the particles to be and when working with just two particles. But even then only the particles would move. I need both charged objects to interact and move.

If you happen to know a workaround with some other force field, please let me know. Maybe with geometry nodes.

Here's the .blend file.
[image]

Comment: It may not be helpful that it only works on particles, but that's how it is. Generally force fields do not work on other force fields - which is what you tried to do there. For example, a _Wind_ force field doesn't blow away another _Wind_ force field (or other force fields). And the other thing is, you parented the force fields to the spheres, not vice versa. In this case even if the charges would have attracted each other, they would have been held back by their parent spheres. Why not use a _Force_ field between the two spheres with a negative strength?